# Flowable.fromIterable never ends. It never reaches .subscribe() - Android RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, flatmap, flowable

I am trying to obtain a `List` of Documents, then trying to send each doc to the server and delete if from the database and phone. The thing is that it looks like it never arrives to the .`subscribe` method of the `Fragment`, it is like is stuck at the .`flatMap` executing the `sendToServer(..)` method. Any help, please?

Fragment:

```
disposable = mViewModel.singleSend()
    .subscribe(sent -> DialogUtils.showMessage(R.string.success)
            , t -> DialogUtils.showMessage(R.string.error_binding_data)
    );
```

ViewModel:

```
public Single<Boolean> singleSend() {

    return sendMediaAttachement()
        .map(list -> !list.contains(false))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());     
}

public @NonNull Single<List<Boolean>> sendMediaAttachement() {

    return mRepository.getAttachedDocs(getMantenValue().getID())
            .concatMap(docs -> Flowable.fromIterable(docs))
            .flatMap(doc -> mRepository.sendToServer(doc, getFileFromAttachedDoc(doc)),
                    (doc, wsResult) -> {
                        if (wsResult.isSuccessful()) deleteDoc(doc);
                        return wsResult.isSuccessful();
                    })
            .toList();
}

public void deleteDoc(DocumentoAdjunto doc) {

    addDisposable(mRepository.delete(doc)
            .subscribe(deleted -> {
                if (deleted)
                    FileUtils.deleteFile(getFileFromAttachedDoc(doc)); //returns void

            }, t -> getToastMessageInteger().setValue(R.string.file_not_deleted)));
}
```

Repository:

```
public @NonNull Flowable<WSResult> sendToServer(DocumentoAdjunto doc, File file) {
    return mRemoteDataSource.uploadFile(doc, file)
            .map(this::parse)
            .toFlowable()
            .doOnError(Timber::e)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
}

public Single<Boolean> delete(DocumentoAdjunto doc) {
    return mLocalDataSource.delete(doc)
            .doOnError(Timber::e)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

Comment: What do you do with that `disposable`?

Comment: You shouldn't execute the subscription from your fragment. It should be done by your viewmodel or a Work. And I assume your `getAttachedDoc` returns a flowable: Room will build it as a never ending flowable giving you updates on the data so you either turn it on a single or you use `first` / `take(1)` the code you posted can't compile, what it does in the flatmap makes no sense, the comma after sendToServer and lambda specifically.

Comment: Actually was not working because of the infinite loop because of the Flowable, as you said. But it was compiling without problem, I don't understand why you said was impossible. Thanks @DanieleSegato

Comment: I dispose it at the end @akarnokd

Comment: why should'nt I subscribe in Fragment? Some google's github samples do it.. @DanieleSegato